# How to swap two files in a GNU make function?

Tags: shell, unix, makefile, gnu

I would like to swap two files using a function / macro when running the `uninstall` target in my Makefile.

Here is what I have which is only leaving one of the files and removing the other two:

```
swap = mv $(1) $(3); mv $(2) $(1); mv $(3) $(2)

uninstall:
    @$(call swap,`printf "%s\n" $(FILE).* | sort -r | sed -n 1p`,\
      $(FILE),$(shell mktemp $(FILE).XXX))
```

Comment: You aren't running that `mktemp` command anywhere. Try `@set -x;$(call ....)` to see what is actually being run. That should help you.

Comment: Local mistake when copy pasting from my editor. I was trying using `ticks` and `$(shell ...)`. I have updated the example.

Comment: The above function actually works, if I simply `$(call 1,2,3)`, the problem is in the `mktemp` somewhere.

Comment: `$(shell)` is the wrong time for that location but that's not related to the problem (it happens at recipe expansion time not at run time for that recipe line).

Comment: Thanks. If $(shell) is wrong, which one would be correct?

Comment: Well... I take that back. That's probably fine. I'd probably do `tmpfile=$$(mktemp $(FILE).xxx); $(call swap,...,$(FILE),$$tmpfile)` but that's a style thing mostly.

Comment: The other thing you could do is stop playing this game and just use a symlink which you can atomically swap out.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Can you post an answer with that alternative?

Comment: Just have a symlink for the "current" file and when you want to install and uninstall just create a new link pointing at the file you want and then `mv` the new link on top of the old link.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what files to swap you could try something like the following. I assume the pairs to swap are `fooXXX, barXXX`.

```
define SWAP_files
swap_$(1):
    @temp=$$(shell mktemp temp.XXXXXX); \
    to_swap_with=$$(patsubst foo%,bar%,$(1)); \
    mv $(1) $$$$temp; \
    mv $$$$to_swap_with $(1); \
    mv $$$$temp $$$$to_swap_with

uninstall: swap_$(1)
endef

$(foreach foo,$(FOOS),$(eval $(call SWAP_files,$(foo))))
```

Foreach `fooXXX` file it instantiates a rule:

```
swap_fooXXX:
    @temp=$(shell mktemp temp.XXXXXX); \
    to_swap_with=$(patsubst foo%,bar%,fooXXX); \
    mv fooXXX $$temp; \
    mv $$to_swap_with fooXXX; \
    mv $$temp $$to_swap_with
```

and a rule:

```
uninstall: swap_fooXXX
```